# Why do these two nouns used in a similar fashion take the singular form in one sentence and yet the plural in the other?

Tags: grammatical-number

> Wenn du für **Gerechtigkeit** kämpfen wolltest, ...
>
> ... Aber das ist kein Grund für **Unachtsamkeiten**.

For what it's worth, in English, both *justice* and *carelessness* are uncountable nouns. I wonder what grammatical rule dictates the use of the singular form *Gerechtigkeit* in the first sentence and yet the plural *Unachtsamkeiten* in the second.

Comment: German doesn't care *carelessness* is uncountable in English. German *Unachtsamkeit* is countable. There isn't a grammatical rule whether to use singular or plural at this place either. It's up to the speaker's choice.

Comment: It is not a question of grammar rules. It is a question of common usage. Grammar allows you to form singular and plural of both words as you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Unachtsamkeit* (and similarly *Unaufmerksamkeit*) actually has to quite similar meanings:

1. A state of mind, where one does not pay attention
2. A mistake, cause by the former

The second meaning can easily be used in plural.

Answer (score 1):

> Gerechtigkeit

This is uncountable and only used in singular.

> Ungerechtigkeit

This can be used both in singular and in plural:

> Es ist eine himmelschreiende Ungerechtigkeit, dass Elmar ein Eis bekommt, aber ich nicht.
>
> Der Lehrer fiel durch viele kleine Ungerechtigkeiten gegenüber seinen Schülern auf.

So it seems the prefix *un-* decides about the countability.

Same for Glück/Unglück. But different for Aufmerksamkeit.

Comment: One could add that, yes, "Gerechtigkeit" is commonly used in singular only, and for those who try to learn German it is a good idea to memorize "singular-only" use of "Gerechtigkeit". However, one could imagine also situations where a plural "Gerechtigkeiten" could be used - most undisputedly in creative writing, poetry, etc. But there are also areas in the humanities where this word form could appear.